# How to retrive action ID with object ID and User ID? (Open Graph Custom Action)

Tags: facebook, object, action, facebook-opengraph

So the situation is such:

I want the user to perform an (unique) action on my page. I do this through the presentation of an interface and a set of objects on my page. Works flawlessly.

But in order to present a complete user interface I must also give the option to delete the performed action, so I must know if a user has already interacted with a certain object.

Now could I run through all the objects, the user has interacted with and check, if the asked object is in there, but this way is not very resource savvy, when the user has interacted with a lot of items.

So the basic question is: Is there an API method, where I can look whether this user has already an action with the given object?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*https://graph.facebook.com/me/**APP_NAMESPACE**:**ACTION_NAME***

This will give you a list of all the actions of type **ACTION_NAME** that the current user has performed.
In the list you'll also find the connected objects.

**Example:**
*https://graph.facebook.com/me/polarprint_forum:ask*

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "10150663311283415", 
      "from": {
        "id": "549348414", 
        "name": "Joakim Syk"
      }, 
      "start_time": "2012-03-08T13:10:44+0000", 
      "end_time": "2012-03-08T13:10:44+0000", 
      "publish_time": "2012-03-08T13:10:44+0000", 
      "application": {
        "id": "346637838687298", 
        "name": "Polar Print Forum"
      }, 
      "data": {
        "question": {
          "id": "10150604589861693", 
          "url": "http://www.polarprint.se/facebook_thread_tab/946/k\u0025C3\u0025A4ppteknik_vid_kullersten.html", 
          "type": "polarprint_forum:question", 
          "title": "käppteknik vid kullersten"
        }
      }, 
      "likes": {
        "count": 0
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0
      }
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/polarprint_forum:ask?format=json&offset=25&limit=25"
  }
}
```

A more efficient approach would probably be to store this information on your end when creating the actions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is, that this data will be quite a big array to search through on a big page. In terms of resources that is not very efficient.

I think it is indeed the best idea to store that action ID in the database and check if it still exists when requested.